# jQuery $.ajax works with GET but fails on POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a really weird problem on a customer's server.
I'm using code like the one posted below in several scripts.
The $.ajax configurations are almost identical (i.e. only file, data and success function change) and always use type:POST.
This works most of the times, but for the case below POST always fails.
Changing the type to GET works without a problem.

I'm a little bit clueless what happens here.

```
var parameter = {
    password : $("#password").val()
};

$.ajax({
    type     : "POST",
    url      : "query/submit_password.php",
    dataType : "xml",
    async    : true,
    data     : parameter,
    success  : function(aXHR) { /* ... */ },
    error    : function(aXHR, aStatus, aError) { alert("Error:\n" + aStatus + "\n"+ aError); }
});
```

This code always results with an alert "NetworkError: A network error occurred.".
Again - other cases with almost identical code work without a problem.
Chrome and Firefox dev tools report a POST error without any further explanation.

Any idea what happens here?

---

A few more details.

- The client's site is hosted on GoDaddy
- The same piece code works well on other servers
- Yes, the file does exist as a GET request works
- All browsers I tried this on have no blocker plugins (like adblock) installed

HTTPScoop shows the following results
(3 attempts, the red status says "Connection closed by communications partner"):

[image: HTTPScoop result]

Chrome shows the following:

[image: Chrome error]

---

Almost solved.
The apache log showed a status 403 on the request.
It also showed a returned size of 0 which probably is the reason why chrome, etc. showed a failed request.
Why this happens is still not clear but it is definitely a server side configuration problem (most likely a mod_rewrite problem or sth. like that).

Comment: Also, network error might mean the requests are not even reaching your server. Check the apache (or any server you are using) logs to make sure

Comment: Maybe it doesn't allow `post` request because it works with `get` as you mentioned, what is used on the server side ?

Comment: Did you also change to using `$_POST` in your PHP while when you are using `type: "POST"` in your AJAX call?

Comment: - The site is hosted on GoDaddy, so I guess there is no chance to see the logs.
I'm always using $_REQUEST in PHP

Comment: Oh - and as I said POST seems to be allowed as several other post requests (even to files in the same folder) work.

Comment: Can you access the same `url` from the browser's address bar ?

Comment: Yes, without problems.

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 how can you access a post request using address bar in browser??

Comment: @charlietfl, the `url` is accessible from address bar but you can't pass data to post using this, I asked `OP` to make sure that the url is really right.

Comment: IMHO the problem has to be somewhere in the server's configuration as the I've tested the code on at least 4 different servers with different PHP+Apache versions and all worked fine.

Comment: Probably not the fix, but try JSON.stringify(parameter) as the "data" value

Comment: What is the target script doing? Maybe writing some files with insufficient permissions?

Comment: use browser console to inspect full ajax request and get as much detail regarding status, what is sent, and what is returned or if request times out. If get a 500 status...have server code problem for example

Comment: "Chrome and Firefox dev tools report a POST error without any further explanation." - this doesn't happen. What's the response code from the post request? 200? 306? 404? 406? 500? Further can you check the .htaccess file to ensure that POST is allowed as opposed to other CRUD methods.

Comment: No, there is no error code displayed anywhere. No 404 or 500 or whatever. The Network request is displayed red, the headers can be shown (and look valid). Preview and Response are empty. Chrome also shows a script error (firefox does not) "POST http://[...]". When I open the callstack the first thing before that error is the send method from jquery.

Comment: And the status columns (Method, Status, Type) just says "POST (failed) Pending"

Comment: I used HTTPScoop on this and it says that the "connection was closed by the communication partner". Again, no error code.

Answer (score 1):

try add contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" to your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type     : "POST",
    url      : "query/submit_password.php",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType : "xml",
    async    : true,
    data     : parameter,
    success  : function(aXHR) { /* ... */ },
    error    : function(aXHR, aStatus, aError) { alert("Error:\n" + aStatus + "\n"+ aError); }
});
```

if it doesn't help try what benhowdle89 says, stringify(parameter).

Comment: I tried both and both don't change a thing (would have surprised me anyway, as I already checked the post headers and they are valid). I'm pretty sure the server has some bad configuration/.htaccess. I'm now waiting for the client's response as I don't have access to the server myself.